# Entity Framework - Map booleans to VARCHAR2(1)

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and ASP.NET Core 2.1.

I've seen several examples on SO and elsewhere for mapping NUMBER(1) columns in the database to boolean in Entity Framework.
They usually involve something like this

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <edmMappings>
      <edmMapping dataType="number">
        <add name="bool" precision="1"/>
      </edmMapping>
    </edmMappings>
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

getting added into the web.config.

All the examples are for mapping a numeric DB value to boolean. The database we are using is has a column ACTIVE_IND in every column, that is a VARCHAR2(1). We are to use it as "1" = true, "0" = false.

Every value I try for `<edmMapping dataType="***">`, I get an error like `DataType 'varchar2' is invalid`. I've tried varchar, varchar2, string, etc.

My question - is there a way to map all tables so that in my .NET code, the property is boolean, but in the database, it is VARCHAR2?

Answer (score 0):

There's no first-class way to do this in EF 6.

EF Core supports this through [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions), and Oracle has shipped [ODP.NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/).  EF Core support, however, hasn't shipped yet.

Comment: But Oracle has not released an EF provider for Core yet, as far as I'm aware. This is why we had to use regular EF 6.0 inside of our .NET Core project. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Got it.  I hadn't noticed that ODP.NET Core had shipped, looks like we're still waiting for the EF Core support: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/odpnet-dotnet-ef-core-sod-4395108.pdf